# How can I flip the dash and underscore keys in macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'd like to remap dash to underscore and vice-versa in macOS Sierra. I type underscore way more frequently than dash, so this is a desirable lifehack. Karabiner doesn't work anymore in Sierra (and the Elements version is a non-starter at this stage), and I can't seem to figure out how to do it in BetterTouchTool or Keyboard Maestro. There seems to be loads of ways to remap keys for *shortcuts*, but flipping the *primary* and *shift* output from the same key is elusive.

Answer (score 2):

Easily done  via a custom layout made with

http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele